# Why compiler implicitly deletes constructor while trying to initialize an array of objects with C++11 style

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to write a very simple constructor init list but falling short on an array of objects. The compiler says:

```
parentclass.cpp:5: error: use of deleted function ‘SubClass::SubClass(SubClass&&)’
     , subObjects{this}
                      ^
```

I'm sure this is a basic concept about Modern C++ and seen many answered questions around. But none of them clarified what I'm missing.

Here's the basic code which creates this compiler error (which is g++ 8.3.0)

**QtCreator Project File:**

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        parentclass.cpp \
        subclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
    parentclass.h \
    subclass.h
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "parentclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ParentClass pClass;

    return a.exec();
}
```

**parentclass.h:**

```
#ifndef PARENTCLASS_H
#define PARENTCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include "subclass.h"

class ParentClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ParentClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private:
    SubClass subObjects[3];
};

#endif // PARENTCLASS_H
```

**parentclass.cpp:**

```
#include "parentclass.h"

ParentClass::ParentClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , subObjects{ {this} }
{
}
```

**subclass.h:**

```
#ifndef SUBCLASS_H
#define SUBCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class SubClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SubClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};

#endif // SUBCLASS_H
```

**subclass.cpp**

```
#include "subclass.h"

SubClass::SubClass(QObject *parent) 
  : QObject(parent)
{
}
```

Creating a dynamic array could be a workaround but I'm trying to adapt to Modern C++. Since I'm mostly an embedded guy, dynamic arrays are also out of question many times.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit Note:**
I've updated the question for a minimum reproducible example.

Also if I use 'explicit' keyword for the constructor of SubClass, this time it gives an error like this:

```
parentclass.cpp:5: error: could not convert ‘(ParentClass*)this’ from ‘ParentClass*’ to ‘SubClass’
     , subObjects{this}
                      ^
```

'explicit' keyword prevents deletion of the constructor but this time compiler does not accept pointer type, even if they are both derived from the same class.

**Next Edit Note:**
Changed subObjects init list with double braces.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/KbHiso)

Comment: Do you get the same error when not using the `Q_OBJECT` macro? When not deriving from `QObject`? It would be nice to have confirmation that this is a QT question. (Plus, knowing which of these two aspects triggers the compiler error would give a solid indication of where to look.)

Comment: Have you tried `subObjects{ this }`, without extra braces? My guess is, `subObjects{ {this} }` is interpreted as `subObjects{ SubClass{this} }` - creating a temporary and then trying to copy or move it into the array element; but QObject is not copyable nor movable.

Comment: Oktalist, I've updated the question for a full project. Now you should be able to reproduce.

JaMiT, I've tried what you've suggested. Unfortunately removing Q_OBJECT macro does not change anything on this subject.

Igor, I had tried and was producing the same result. You're right, this is probably trying to copy the QObject. But still, removing extra braces doesn't solve the issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This example is *very* far from minimal. Try to come up with a single source file, no framework dependencies.

Comment: `subObjects` is an array of type `SubObject`. You are trying to ibitialise it with a *pointer* to an object of an *unrelated* class `ParentObject`. What is your intent?

Comment: n.m., while I was checking Oktalist's comment, I've seen that indeed the first code was not producing an error. So the problem could be the framework dependency. Removing it could hide the problem. (Another part of the error is mentioning Q_DISABLE_COPY macro)

By the way, I'm trying to have 3 SubClass objects which are defined as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the explanation in this [link](https://www.cleanqt.io/blog/why-qobject-subclasses-are-not-copyable), which I was suspecting already.

This is a design choice by the developers of Qt. They made QObject class non-copyable for various reasons, including not messing up with the SIGNALS/SLOTS mechanism.

For a workaround, I'll define the subObjects as an array of SubClass* pointers, then create 3 instances with new keyword in the constructor of ParentClass.

**P.S.:** Oktalist, this is why your code is not producing the error. QObject has to be completely defined as in the Qt framework.